# Run two logstash instance in same machine

Tags: logstash

I want to run two `logstash` instance in same machine. Now i am starting the `logstash` by using the command.`logstash.bat agent -f logstashconf.conf`. But when i am going to start the second instance via same command results some port binding issues. So is there is any parameter available that user can explicitly configure the port by using command line?. Also is there is any further issues happens while i running more than one instance of `logstash` in same machine?

Comment: Logstash doesn't bind to any port by default, so the problem must be with your configuration. The two configuration files obviously both have plugins that listen to the same port.

Comment: Please upload your issue logs and your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you can copy your logstash folder to a new folder and run another instance within the new folder.
and you can change config file to specify different path.data